# Entity Framework no encuentra 'System.Data.SqlClient'

Tags: .net, entity-framework

Despues de estar instalando y desinstalando EF 6.1.3 en varias proyectos de mi solución, a la hora de querer usarlo tuve el siguiente problema:

> No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient'. Make sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the application config file. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.

A EF lo tengo envuelto(*wrappeado*), para evitar referenciar los ensamblados de EF en otros proyectos, con el patrón de Unidad de Trabajo.

Estuve investigando por SOen en las siguientes preguntas y no pudieron resolver mi problema:

- [No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18455747/3817681)
- [No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient'.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21175713/3817681)
- [Entity Framework Provider type could not be loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14033193/3817681)
- [Error: No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21641435/3817681)

Elegí no aplicar las siguiente soluciones por que, según mi opinión, generan dudas su implementación y son *walk-arounds*:

- Cargar el ensamblado a lo Java; haciendo una llamada la instancia del proveedor.
- Referenciar en el proyecto inicial el EF, junto a su proveedor.
- Hacer una copia posterior a la compilación del archivo `EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despues de toquetear bastante lo resolví borrando las entradas relacionadas a EF en los `app.config` de cada proyecto de la solución, a excepción de donde implemento *Code First*.

Al parecer, cuando EF quiere cargar el ensamblado del proveedor de *SqlServer*, va a buscar tal ensamblado al proyecto donde tiene la definición del proveedor y donde se hace la llamada *inicial* (la primera llamada de la pila de llamadas). En mi caso, era el proyecto donde tenia los formularios de Windows, en la capa de presentación.

Igual, antes de darme cuenta de esto, realice la siguiente lista de verificaciones para poder resolver posibles problemas intermedios.

1. Desinstalé EF de toda la solución, ya sea por NuGet o la consola de paquetes.
2. Borré las referencias huérfanas de todos los proyectos.
3. Borré los ensamblados huérfanos de todos los proyectos.

Luego de ello, procedí con la reinstalación de EF:

1. Instalé EF vía consola de paquetes al proyecto deseado: `Install-Package EntityFramework`
2. Verifique que la referencia de `EntityFramework.SqlServer` haga copia local.